# Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed) - React Native web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, expo, react-native-web

I have a React Native app that needs to be served on its web version. So, I need to implement the Google OAuth with the firebase js lib.

I'm following [these steps](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google).

If I use the same code from the docs I have a weird error (of course I put the proper config object in the initializeApp method):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { ResponseType } from 'expo-auth-session';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp({
  /* Config */
});

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function App() {

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'Your-Web-Client-ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    },
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { id_token } = response.params;
      const auth = getAuth();
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
      signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
    }
  }, [response]);

  return (
    <Button
      disabled={!request}
      title="Login"
      onPress={() => {
        promptAsync();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

The error is:
[image]

I get this error specifically when I call `signInWithCredential()`

The strange thing is that in the `Network` tab (Chrome DevTools) I have a successful response:

[image]
[image]

And the problem is: If I want to get the user information with `onAuthStateChanged`, it is null because the login attempt just failed (despite the dev-tools being all good)

Note: I've tried with a new starter project, moving our dependencies with the same version as they are here and it's working.
But I can't figure out what can be happening with this project.

**EDIT**: Adding images of the requests that are being made:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of all requests made? There might be another request as well?

Comment: @Dharmaraj. sure, I just edited the post at the very bottom